# Avoiding a full table scan in Spark on a partitioned Hive table when joining two tables

Tags: apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables stored in Hive, one which records when a device performs a given conversion event and another which holds records for all the events which happen on all devices.

```
CREATE TABLE conversions (
  deviceid string,
  timestamp datetime,
  date string
)
CREATE TABLE event_log (
  deviceid string,
  timestamp datetime,
  date string
)
```

The date field holds the date part of the timestamp in YYYYMMDD format, and the event_log table is partitioned by this column. The conversions table is small (typically 100's of rows) but the event_log table is large, containing approximately 15 million rows on a daily basis.

I would like to extract from the event_log the history of the devices on the day of them having a conversion event.

My first attempt at this was as below

```
select * from event_log a left semi join conversions b
on (a.deviceid = b.deviceid and a.date = b.date)
```

However this seems to perform a full table scan on the event_log which is making the query extremely slow. Tez seems to be able to perform the query efficiently without performing a full scan by filtering event_log prior to the join.

What is the canonical way of performing this query in SparkSQL? I am happy to use the dataframe api if it is more easily expressed in that format